# Create Windows local account from Linux without installing sshd or web service on the Windows server

Tags: linux, perl, wmi

I want to write a Perl/Python problem running on Linux that creates a local user account on a Windows server.  I found suggestions that install sshd or web service on the Windows server first.  However, I don't want to install program on the Windows so the server is clean.  Is there a Perl module or toolkit can create a user on Windows?

Note:
I also tried WMI client (WMIC) for Linux, but I didn't find out how to execute a command using the VMI client.

Comment: This is a WMI question.  What language you use to code to that protocol is irrelevant until you know how to use the WMI API.

Comment: DavidO you are right that we can use WMI to create users.  I found document using WMI object to create users, but it's under Windows.  I want to know how can I use WMI on Linux.

Comment: You might have to adapt this for your Linux flavor's particular needs.  Written in Python.  http://packages.ubuntu.com/hardy/python/wmi-client    Here's how I found it:  Searched Google for terms "windows wmi linux".  Follow the link to the Wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation  .  Look in the footnotes (#8).